# Date field format in JTable

Tags: java, swing

While I retrieve a date field from access database and show it in JTable, it is in yyyy-MM-dd format. I want it to be dd-MM-yyyy. Though I changed the format in MS Access, while it is shown in panel it is in yyyy-MM-dd only. How can I change it?

The date field is one of the many fields I retrieve with a query. So, I don't understand where to put the SimpleDateFormatter and format it for each row. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Locale;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.text.*;

public class gc implements ActionListener
{
JComboBox cc=new JComboBox();
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
JTable table;
DefaultTableModel model;
String query;
int i;
JPanel panel=new JPanel();

public gc()
{
frame.setTitle("Composition Check");
frame.setSize(500,500);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
JPanel p1=new JPanel();
p1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

//Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
//  System.out.println("Before setting, Locale is = " + locale); 
//Locale.setDefault(Locale.English);
//System.out.println("Before setting, Locale is = " + locale); 

try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select DISTINCT composition from try");

while(rs.next())
{
 cc.addItem(rs.getString("composition"));
}

conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}

p1.add(cc);
cc.addActionListener(this);
frame.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);

frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel
{
public Class getColumnClass(int col) 
{
    if (col == 3) 
    {
        return java.util.Date.class;
    }
}
}

public void addTable(String query)
{
try
{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:vasantham","","");
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
System.out.println(query);
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData md=rs.getMetaData();
int cols=md.getColumnCount();
//table=new JTable();
model=new DefaultTableModel();

model.addColumn("Purpose");
model.addColumn("Name");
model.addColumn("Manu");
model.addColumn("Expiry");
model.addColumn("Stock");
model.addColumn("Cost");
model.addColumn("Supplier");
model.addColumn("Supplier Number");
model.addColumn("Rack");

table=new JTable(new MyTableModel());

String[] tabledata=new String[cols];
int i=0;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

while(rs.next())
{
for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
{
//if(i==3)
//{
 //System.out.println(rs.getObject(i+1).toString()); 
// tabledata[i]=formatter.format(rs.getObject(i+1).toString());
//}

 tabledata[i]=rs.getObject(i+1).toString();

}
model.addRow(tabledata);

}

panel.removeAll();
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table); 
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

panel.add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
conn.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
String ac=(String)cc.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(ac);

addTable("select * from try where composition='"+ac+"'");
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
new gc();
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize the table model to tell the JTable that the column is holding values of type Date:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int col) {
    if (col == 3) {
        return java.util.Date.class;
    }
    // return the appropriate class for every column
}
```

This will make the JTable use a renderer formatting the date with the format associated to the current locale. If you need another format, you need to associate another renderer to the column, which formats the date as you want to.

Comment: Where should I add this in my coding, Sir? and also, how to call, Sir?

Comment: This method should be a methof of your table model. If you don't know what a TableModel is, then definitely read the JTable tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Sir, I have uploaded my entire coding. I have included the class too. But I get '}' return statement missing, eventhough nothing is missing sir.

Comment: You should return the appropriate class for every column. You only return a class for the column at index 3. And since a method must return something whatever the column index is, it should end with `else { return super.getColumnClass(col); }`.

Comment: Sir, I used it. But still I get the same kind of output, in yyyy-MM-dd format along with time.

Comment: Sir, I used `SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
TableCellRenderer renderer = new FormatRenderer( format );` and inside the while loop for rs I used `table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(renderer);` But it doesnt make any changes, sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
tabledata[i]=rs.getObject(i+1).toString();
```

This means you do not seem to care about the type of the column; everything is simply taken as a String.

2 ways to 'solve' your issue. Either read it as a date (when type == date) and then format appropriately or use a custom cell renderer on your table. E.g.: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked!

```
while(rs.next())
{
for(i=0;i<cols;i++)
{
if(i==3)
{   
Date intr=(rs.getDate(i+1));
tabledata[i]=formatter.format(intr);
}
else
 tabledata[i]=rs.getObject(i+1).toString();
}
model.addRow(tabledata);
}
```

Thanks to JB Nizet and TheStijn, whose ideas were informative!

Comment: while possible (and "working", as you noticed) that's not how Swing JTable/TableModel is supposed to be used: typically, you add the real object to the model, then let a renderer handle its visual representation, just a @JB Nizet already explained. Don't forget to read and understand the tutorial eventually :-)