# How to set date value into JDateChooser field when clicked JTable row?

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I want to fill all the fields when I click on a table row. If I click a row in table it fills all the `JTextField` & `JComboBox` components, but not the `JDateChooser`.

How could I fill date chooser field when I select a row in table?

This is the code:

```
 private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    int SelectedRowIndex=jTable1.getSelectedRow();

    jComboBox2.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 0));
    jComboBox2.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 0));
    jComboBox3.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 1));
    jComboBox3.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 1));
    jTextField2.setText((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 2));
    jComboBox5.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 3));
    jComboBox5.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 3));
    jComboBox6.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 4));

    jComboBox6.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 4));
    jTextField6.setText((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 5));
    jComboBox14.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 6));
    jComboBox14.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 6));
    jTextField5.setText((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 7));
    jComboBox13.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 8));
    jComboBox13.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 8));
    jComboBox4.addItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 9));
    jComboBox4.setSelectedItem((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 9));
    jTextField3.setText((String)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 10));
    java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser2.getDate().getTime());
    date1.setDate((int)jTable1.getValueAt(SelectedRowIndex, 11));
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: BTW - the last two lines of that code seem completely illogical. Firstly while most of the code is getting values from the table, those two lines initially get the date from the date chooser. Secondly that date is **then** set to the value from the table, then immediately discarded! Probably best to create an SQL date from the value in the table, then **set** that date in the date chooser.

Comment: I don't know why you would be casting the date value to an int. You should be storing a Date Object in the TableModel.

Comment: JTable model with a Date column : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11503696/3992939

Comment: Start with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880675/230513) to prepare your [mcve].